# Facing "AssertionError" in python while decoding avro formatted data

Tags: python, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I am facing **"AssertionError"** while decoding **avro formatted** data coming from **kafka** topic, we have used **apicurio tool** to encode data at kafka end. I am using **python 3.11.6**, Code I am using is as follows:

```
try:
    import kafka
    import json
    import requests
    import os
    import sys
    from json import dumps
    from kafka import KafkaProducer

    from kafka import KafkaConsumer
    from confluent_kafka.schema_registry import SchemaRegistryClient
    import io
    from confluent_kafka import Consumer, KafkaError
    from avro.io import DatumReader, BinaryDecoder
    import avro.schema

    from confluent_kafka.avro.serializer.message_serializer import MessageSerializer
    from confluent_kafka.avro.cached_schema_registry_client import CachedSchemaRegistryClient
    from confluent_kafka.avro.serializer import (SerializerError,  # noqa
                                                 KeySerializerError,
                                                 ValueSerializerError)

    print("ALL ok")
except Exception as e:
    print("Error : {} ".format(e))


SCHEME_REGISTERY = "http://localhost:8082"
TOPIC = "abc"
BROKER = "localhost:9092"

schema = """
{
   "type":"record",
   "name":"Envelope",
   "namespace":"abc",
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"before",
         "type":[
            "null",
            {
               "type":"record",
               "name":"Value",
               "fields":[
                  {
                     "name":"field1",
                     "type":"double"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"field2",
                     "type":[
                        "null",
                        "string"
                     ],
                     "default":null
                  }
               ],
               "connect.name":"abc.Value"
            }
         ],
         "default":null
      },
      {
         "name":"after",
         "type":[
            "null",
            "Value"
         ],
         "default":null
      },
      {
         "name":"source",
         "type":{
            "type":"record",
            "name":"Source",
            "namespace":"io.debezium.connector.oracle",
            "fields":[
               {
                  "name":"version",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"connector",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"name",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"ts_ms",
                  "type":"long"
               },
               {
                  "name":"snapshot",
                  "type":[
                     {
                        "type":"string",
                        "connect.version":1,
                        "connect.parameters":{
                           "allowed":"true,last,false,incremental"
                        },
                        "connect.default":"false",
                        "connect.name":"io.debezium.data.Enum"
                     },
                     "null"
                  ],
                  "default":"false"
               },
               {
                  "name":"db",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"sequence",
                  "type":[
                     "null",
                     "string"
                  ],
                  "default":null
               },
               {
                  "name":"schema",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"table",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"txId",
                  "type":[
                     "null",
                     "string"
                  ],
                  "default":null
               },
               {
                  "name":"scn",
                  "type":[
                     "null",
                     "string"
                  ],
                  "default":null
               },
               {
                  "name":"commit_scn",
                  "type":[
                     "null",
                     "string"
                  ],
                  "default":null
               },
               {
                  "name":"lcr_position",
                  "type":[
                     "null",
                     "string"
                  ],
                  "default":null
               },
               {
                  "name":"rs_id",
                  "type":[
                     "null",
                     "string"
                  ],
                  "default":null
               },
               {
                  "name":"ssn",
                  "type":[
                     "null",
                     "int"
                  ],
                  "default":null
               },
               {
                  "name":"redo_thread",
                  "type":[
                     "null",
                     "int"
                  ],
                  "default":null
               }
            ],
            "connect.name":"io.debezium.connector.oracle.Source"
         }
      },
      {
         "name":"op",
         "type":"string"
      },
      {
         "name":"ts_ms",
         "type":[
            "null",
            "long"
         ],
         "default":null
      },
      {
         "name":"transaction",
         "type":[
            "null",
            {
               "type":"record",
               "name":"ConnectDefault",
               "namespace":"io.confluent.connect.avro",
               "fields":[
                  {
                     "name":"id",
                     "type":"string"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"total_order",
                     "type":"long"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"data_collection_order",
                     "type":"long"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ],
         "default":null
      }
   ],
   "connect.name":"abc.tablename.Envelope"
}
"""


schema = avro.schema.Parse(schema)
reader = DatumReader(schema)


def decode_method_2(msg_value):
    message_bytes = io.BytesIO(msg_value)
    message_bytes.seek(5)
    decoder = BinaryDecoder(message_bytes)
    event_dict = reader.read(decoder)
    return event_dict

def main():
    print("Listening *****************")

    consumer = KafkaConsumer(
        TOPIC,
        bootstrap_servers=[BROKER],
        auto_offset_reset='latest',
        enable_auto_commit=False
    )

    for msg in consumer:
        msg_value = msg.value
        print("\n")
        print("decode_method_2", decode_method_2(msg_value))
        print("\n")

main()
```

**Error** I am facing is as follows:

AssertionError: b'\xf0@\x02 ABCRequest\x161.9.7.Final\x0cabc-xyz-xyz.abc.com\xb0\xe4\xdb\xd0\xf2b\x00\x08true\x0esystem\x00\x10abccard\ntablename\x00\x02\x12601987152\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x02r\x02\xac\x90\xc9\xbf\xf2b\x00'

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need both `kafka-python` and `confluent-kafka-python` installed and imported.
2. Your schema should be in the registry, so you dont need to provide/parse as a string, in code. Instead, you should use HTTP functions to download it.
3. The documentation of confluent library shows how to consume avro data from their registry, which should also work for apicurio. Specifically, it does not require parsing an Avro schema, but rather providing AvroDeserializer instance to the consumer

   https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/examples/avro_consumer.py

Comment: I am facing following error while trying to ran above given example with apicurio.

{"message":"RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8082/schemas/ids/0","error_code":404,"detail":"NotFoundException: RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8082/schemas/ids/0","name":"NotFoundException"}

Comment: I haven't used Apicurio registry, but it seems that you may need to provide a different `schema.registry.url` config for it to be "Confluent compatible" perhaps? Basically, your error is saying it doesn't have a route for `/schemas/ids/X`